# Georeferencer Error

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, georeferencing

I added 5 points in the Georeferencer, but it didnt show in the QGIS XYZ Tiles.
When I click the `Start Georeferencing` it shows the error.

```
QGIS version: 3.26.3
Raster: .jpg
XYZ Tiles: OSM
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried opening the settings (yellow gear icon) and just closing them again, then hit Start? I think there's a bug so I have to do that from time to time.

Comment: Have you tried to select some other transformation than Linear from the Transformation settings?

Comment: Yup, it works in `Transformation Type - Thin Plate Spine`, thanks.